# How to allow signup only via nodejs Backend in firebase email/pass authentication?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting the user to fill in a form with some extra information. So, whenever the form is filled, my backend uses **CreateUser()** function of the **firebase-admin** package and then adds some entries to the **Real-Time Database** based on the user entries.

Now, I am allowing the user to sign in using the **front-end firebase client**. My concern is that since I am exposing my **firebase config** on the frontend, can a user not modify the script and manually use **CreateUserWithEmailAndPassword()** on the frontend and add an entry to my firebase authentication. This way, they are able to skip the addition of those extra entries I make to the **Real-Time Database**.

`Is there a way by which I can add any rules to the firebase authentication which allows sign up only via the **service accounts json** and not the frontend client?`

Aim: Allow user to sign up using backend and add some entries to real-time db.
Allow to user to signin but providing custom user tokens from backend.
I could have gone with manual authentication using mongoDB, but I am using firebase so that I am able to use its password reset, email verification, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, your answer was really helpful. It made sense. I got confused between things because I was trying to use firebase backend in conjunction with my nodeJS backend. I didn't give your solution a try, but I switched a nodeJS backend entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unfortunately no way to *enable* sign-in, yet *disable* sign-up in Firebase Authentication.

The best workaround I can think of is to [inject a custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) into your user profiles when you create them from your back-end, and then check for the existence of that claim in your client-side code, server-side code, and security rules. Since it's not possible to inject such a claim from the client-side SDKs, you can be assured that client-side created accounts won't have the claim.